# Cannot get single block syntax highlighting to work

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I've tried at various times to have code-blocks with different syntax highlighting.
That is important if a question/answer contains source code in different languages, or you want to suppress distracting highlighting of example input/output.

Here a quote of what I tried:

```
C source:<!-- language: lang-c -->

    int main(void)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

Now directly without quotes:

C source:

```
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

AFAICT, I followed the guide in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) exactly, but it does not work. (`language-all` is *not* an option)

Comment: You have to put a blank line _before_ and _after_ the html comment.

Comment: @gunr2171: Thanks, that got it done.

Comment: You can always press the edit button on somebody else's question / answer if you see them using something you like. Then you can see exactly how they did it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The comment has to be put on a *separate line*, with blank lines before and after (e.g. its own Markdown paragraph):

```
C source:

<!-- language: lang-c -->

    int main(void)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

The extra lines are not part of the rendered output:

> C source:
>
> ```c
> int main(void)
> {
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: Stress the blank lines before and after the comment, and I'll accept it whenever I can.

Comment: There you go :-) I've worked with Markdown so much now I 'separate line' and 'separate paragraph' are almost synonymous now.

Comment: Should probably be worked into the markdown help page, too...